# How to show list of keyboards

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard

I have created my own custom keyboard and I want to show list of keyboards view as Apple does. How can I reach this?

[image]

Comment: It is possible only in iOS 10. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956329/proper-implementation-of-handleinputmodelist-in-custom-keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

[Apple documentation for developing custom keyboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW1) says (emphasis mine):

> To ask the system to switch to another keyboard, call the
>   `advanceToNextInputMode` method of the `UIInputViewController` class. The
>   system picks the appropriate “next” keyboard; **there is no API to
>   obtain a list of enabled keyboards or for picking a particular
>   keyboard to switch to**.

Note that you **must** provide a way to get to the next keyboard using the above method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible since iOS 10

If you have an `UIButton` called `nextKeyboardButton` just add that in your `viewDidLoad` function.

```
nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleInputModeList(from:with:)), for: .allTouchEvents)
```

`handleInputModeList` is part of `UIInputViewController`