# Proper implementation of handleInputModeList in Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

A new API has been added in iOS 10 to present the list of other keyboards the user can switch to - the same list that appears when users long press the globe on a system keyboard. The declaration of the function is as follows:
`func handleInputModeList(from view: UIView, with event: UIEvent)`

My question is, what's the proper way to generate a `UIEvent` to supply? I was planning to call this function using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` but this API doesn't reveal `UIEvent`s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was going about this the wrong way. No need for custom gesture handling. As noted in the headers, one should add a target-action to the control they want to trigger this, like so:

Objective-C:
`[keyboardButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleInputModeListFromView:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];`

Swift:
`keyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleInputModeList(from:with:)), for: UIControlEvents.allTouchEvents)`

Comment: If I do this, my keyboard crashes with an SIGQUIT error. I'm going to stick to creating an action for my nextKeyboardButton and call advanceToNextInputMode() when it is pressed.